# Array of DOM elements output casts to String

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Я столкнулся с проблемой с выводом сгенерированных элементов DOM.

```
function createDomElements(man) {
  const { name, image, height, weight} = man;

  const manDetails = createElement({ tagName: 'div', className: 'modal-body' });
  const elementData = [createElement({ tagName: 'span', className: 'man-name' }).innerText = name
    , createElement({ tagName: 'img', className: 'man-image', src: image })
    , createElement({ tagName: 'span', className: 'man-height' }).innerText = height
    , createElement({ tagName: 'span', className: 'man-weight' }).innerText = weight]

  elementData.forEach((element) => manDetails.append(element))
  return manDetails;
}
```

Мне нужно добавить внутренний текст в каждом, но когда я делаю это, элементы приводятся к String.
У меня нет возможности добавить его с атрибутом CSS content. Любые идеи?

Comment: createElement creates initial DOM element

Comment: Понял, буду знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы прямо в массиве создаете элемент и сразу же ему сетите текстовое значение, то результатом присваивания является, собственно, присваиваемое значение.
Итого слева направо

```
createElement(...) => element
    element.innerHTML = text => text


const a = 5 // => 5
const b = true // => true
divEl.innerHTML = 'From Russia with fever' // => 'From Russia with fever'
```

И поэтому `append` ожидает `Node` или `DomString` в качестве аргумента, получает `String`, и добавляет текстовый узел в DOM.

Можно создать свой jQuery.

```
const createElement = tagName => {
  const _el = document.createElement(tagName);
  return {
    className(_cl) {
      _el.className = _cl;
      return _el;
    },
    innerHTML(html) {
      _el.innerHTML = html;
      return _el;
    },
    src(_src) {
      _el.src = _src;
      return _el;
    }
  }
}
```

И заполняйте массив примерно так:

```
const elementData = [
  createElement('span').className('man-name').innerHTML(name)
  ...и дальше по тексту
];
```

В конце концов, если не хотите создавать свою функцию, а менять `createElement` нет возможности, то просто объявите переменные:

```
name, image, width, height
```

Положите их в массив после всех присваиваний и конфигураций

```
const elementData = [name, image, width, height];
container.append(elementData);
```

Comment: Да, я это понимаю, но всё дело в том, что у меня нет возможности поменять функцию createElement и нужно запихнуть данные в элементы именно в этой функции. Можно спокойно добавлять по-одному в родительский элемент и всё будет работать корректно. Но мне просто интересно, есть ли способ это всё дело завернуть в массив. Я пытался создать на месте элемента массива функцию, которая создавала готовый элемент, но когда я выполнял общую функцию, в массиве лежало тело функции, а не готовый элемент, который она должна вернуть.

Comment: Так проблема описана неверно. Никакие элементы к `String` не приводятся. Это вы лично ожидаете, что после присваивания вы получите `Node`.
Обновил ответ, как вариант